# SQLAlchemy: can't compare date attribute with datetime.date object

Tags: python, sql, date, datetime, sqlalchemy

In my database (MariaDB) I have a column with data of type `VARCHAR`. The data actually represents date texts. For this reason, when accessing it I used the `@property` decorator to convert the text into a Python `datetime.date` object:

```
@property
def data(self):
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')
   try:
       return datetime.strptime(self.doc_coletor, '%d/%B/%Y')
   except ValueError:
       return None
```

The result looks like this:

| Original (`string`) | Parsed (`datetime object`) |
| --- | --- |
| 09/agosto/2021 | 2021-08-09 00:00:00 |
| 08/agosto/2021 | 2021-08-08 00:00:00 |
| 07/agosto/2021 | 2021-08-07 00:00:00 |

However, when trying to perform a filter by SQLAlchemy, the query returns no results, even though they exist in practice:

```
self.cpj.query(Coletor).filter(
            Coletor.data == datetime.datetime(2021-08-06 00:00:00)
        ).all()
```

Expected output:
`[<Coletor object at 0x00000199E7255190>, <Coletor object at 0x00000199E7255191>, <Coletor object at 0x00000199E7255192>, ...]`
Actual output:
`[]`

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to create a [hybrid attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).

Comment: That's it, @snakecharmerb! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the question!

Apparently, it is not possible to query the database with the attributes created by SQLAlchemy at the level of the program that is running. Therefore, it will be necessary to invoke a second comparison operation, to evaluate the date values after the property (@property) conversion.